# How to retain hexadecimal code in xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, hex

How to retain hexadecimal code in xslt transformation?

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
<root>
   <p>This is sample character &#x000ED;</p>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
<root>
   <p aid:pstyle="para">This is sample character &#x000ED;</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version do you need for the transformation (1.0 or 2.0) and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use a character-map to control output serialization. You'll find the relevant part of the XSL specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps).

Note that there are other issues with your code. A stylesheet must contain a template that can be triggered, for example `xsl:template match="/"`. Otherwise, nothing is serialized anyway.

Also, I do not see how this relates to an input XML document, since the content comes solely from your XSLT stylesheet.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output use-character-maps="my-map" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:character-map name="my-map">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x000ED;" string="&amp;#x000ED;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <root>
      <p pstyle="para">This is sample character &#x000ED;</p>
   </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p pstyle="para">This is sample character &#x000ED;</p>
</root>
```